# Cross platform full screen HTML5 background images with apache cordova

Tags: html, cordova-3, intel-xdk

In short, How to design the full screen background images (maintaining the aspect ratio) for HTML5 (to be ported to different platforms/ devices)?

Im using Intel XDK/ Apache cordova-3.x  for building an HTML5 app. From this [link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens) i understand, that i can configure different images for the splash screen/ icon for different resolutions/ screen sizes.

And Is there any way i can specify my background images just like the splash screen image? Or should i use a responsive HTML design as mentioned at this [link](https://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/)?

Comment: Cordova use only WebView after the splash screen. You need to use a responsive HTML design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using responsive design leveraging CSS for setting your images' height and width to 100% or use media queries for various screen sizes.

For example,

```
/*Background Full Screen Image*/ 
body {
    background: url("images/img.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/*Background Full Screen Image if the document is smaller than 300 pixels wide*/
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
   body {
        background: url("images/img.png");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }
}
```